# to many thumbnail in details page

Tags: magento2

Why are there so many thumbnails when I first go to the details page?
After a while, it was gone

[image]

Comment: clear cache & check in different browser

Answer (score 0):

Because Js not loaded in your browser and your images get to load first with HTML. and then when Js get loaded in your device it removes all other unwanted images.

Simple
Happy coding